# overwrite the search function in wordpress (sql and php)

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to overwrite the default search function in wordpress? I have tried using the filters, but they only allow adding to the query... or possibly rewriting the whole query using posts_request. If I overwrite that though, no other querys will work. I have the following code

```
function my_posts_request_filter($input)
{
    if ( is_search() && isset($_GET['s'])) {
        global $wpdb;
    }
    return $input;
}

add_filter('posts_request','my_posts_request_filter');
```

I could override $input with my custom SQL, but there is a widget on the page which shows recent posts and that wouldn't show if I do this. Is there a way to JUST overwrite the search function??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't bulletproof, but assuming the first `WP_Query` call is for the search request (there *might* be a scenario where a plugin calls it before WordPress does, but it is unlikely), you can strip the filter once the function runs.

```
function my_posts_request_filter($input)
{
    if ( is_search() && isset($_GET['s'])) {
        global $wpdb;

        // do your funky SQL

        remove_filter('posts_request','my_posts_request_filter');
    }
    return $input;
}
```

Comment: thanks v much! that's done the trick. I don't suppose you know HOW this works? I have overridden $input with my custom SQL and that works - showing the posts. But, it's VERY specific. I would also like to do the general search. (which searches the words in the default way)

Comment: Is there a way to do my custom SQL and THEN do the $input SQL?

Comment: Sorry Matt, I'm not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: Thank you so much ! It's save my day !!