# WP search function to search custom table

Tags: wordpress, search, customization

Now here's something I can't even find on google.
Does anyone here know how I can change the search function in wordpress to search only inside one custom table with a few fields?
I've been wrecking my brain over this. I can't even find a plugin that lets you define your own table and fields in the db.

Can anyone help? (by the way I think that might be a really handy plugin, if it doesn't already exist.)

Thanks in advance!

edit: I've seen this [Topic on wordpress search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144432/how-do-i-search-a-custom-database-table-not-a-wordpress-table?rq=1)
The thing is I tried taking the phpacademy search engine tutorial, never got anything out of the search, and the forum people there weren't too helpful, so to say. 
I'm just doing this for my dad, pro bono, so if anyone could point me in the right direction, I can do the programming, using copy pase etc. but I'm baffled by the search function in query.php (wp).

Answer (score 1):

With the 'search everything' plugin you can search any custom fields or taxonomies. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-everything/faq/

Otherwise you could to go with a custom query ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries), using the `posts_request` filter
(as seen here [overwrite the search function in wordpress (sql and php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025174/overwrite-the-search-function-in-wordpress-sql-and-php))

Answer (score 0):

As you said you want to search in the custom table and on selected fields why don't you create you own wordpress template file and use the search query with the custom sql in that?.

see more one this link
http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/how-do-i-search-a-custom-table